# Loop Serialised Form Fields in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am receiving a serialized string into a PHP function (sent via Ajax to PHP). Let's say it looks like this:

```
year=1923&season=Winter&person_1_name=barry&person_1_age=20&person_2_name=Tom&person_3_name=Jane&person_3_age=30
```

I need to know how in PHP to split those numbered fields out so I can do something with them, like:

```
foreach ( person_x as person ) {
    // do something here with person_x's details
}
```

Also I can't generalise the information I will receive as some may not have all the info (note person_2 does not have an age in the above example) and there will be an unknown number of these fields (they are repeatable in the form)

Comment: how about using the unserialize function and then looping over the obtained array 2 indices at a time?

Comment: Use `parse_str` funciton.

Comment: I updated my example slightly to show that I am also receiving other data from the form so looping all the data won't work. I think I need to loop the specific field names (as to exclude all other fields that don't start with person_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `parse_str()` **Recommended method**

```
$string = 'year=1923&season=Winter&person_1_name=barry&person_1_age=20&person_2_name=Tom&person_3_name=Jane&person_3_age=30';

parse_str($string, $output);
foreach ($output as $key => $person){
 echo $key  . " = " . $person . "<br />";
}
```

Using `explode()`

```
$string = 'year=1923&season=Winter&person_1_name=barry&person_1_age=20&person_2_name=Tom&person_3_name=Jane&person_3_age=30';

$persons = explode("&", $string);    
foreach ($persons as $person){
  $details = explode("=", $person); 
  echo $details[0] . " = " . $details[1] . "<br />";
}
```

Output:

```
year = 1923
season = Winter
person_1_name = barry
person_1_age = 20
person_2_name = Tom
person_3_name = Jane
person_3_age = 30
----------
year = 1923
season = Winter
person_1_name = barry
person_1_age = 20
person_2_name = Tom
person_3_name = Jane
person_3_age = 30
```

Exclude all other fields that don't start with `person_`

```
parse_str($string, $output);
foreach ($output as $key => $person){
 if(preg_match('/person_/', $key)){
   echo $key  . " = " . $person . "<br />";
 }
}
```

Output:

```
person_1_name = barry
person_1_age = 20
person_2_name = Tom
person_3_name = Jane
person_3_age = 30
```

Comment: I updated my example slightly to show that I am also receiving other data from the form so looping all the data won't work. I think I need to loop the specific field names (as to exclude all other fields that don't start with person_). Is this possible?

Comment: in your explode example you are missing the e`xplode('&', $string)` bit. Not that i find explode a very elegant example :)

Comment: @DamienOvereem Thanks ;) I missed that line while copy-pasted from the tested file.

Comment: NP.. as for the OP.. please use the parse_str method :)

Comment: @ScottL I see, you want to exclude all other fields that don't start with `person_`. Check the update.